# pre-boot level virtualization

Tags: windows-7, boot, virtualization

Here is the scenario I'm trying to achieve. Any help towards it is much appreciated.

I would like to setup a computer on which I can virtualize the OS at the pre-boot level with the ability to create snapshots of the install. Perhaps using some sort of boot loader like GRUB (or Windows-compatible equivalent). I could then using a function key during boot to get into an environment to manage the virtual OS (Windows) and associated snapshots (revert, create new, delete).

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Kamal

Comment: it sounds like you are looking for a bare-metal hypervisor, but to be honest I'm having trouble telling what you mean by "Pre-boot level"

Comment: Hi Frank, so, when I power on the PC, if I don't interrupt the boot, I want the PC to boot into Windows. But, I also want to be able to press a key, ala F8, and boot into an environment that lets me manage the snapshots for the Windows OS I have running on that PC.

Comment: I do not believe such a system exists. you are asking a Windows install to be both virtual and physical at the same time.

Comment: How about install those OS(s) on different partition and freeze it use something like deep freeze/shadow defender?

Comment: Thanks Susilo. I thought about doing that but it seems like a cumbersome method.

@FrankThomas, thanks for your feedback. I wasn't sure if there wasn't anything that didn't exist like this out there. Just to be clear, I'm OK with the OS being full screen inside a VM in the setup I described but I can understand why something like this doesn't exist.

Comment: lack of abstraction when running directly on hardware. you can either run through a hypervisor and target virtual hardware (and diff tracking so snapshots work) or you can work on bare metal, targeting the physical hardware, with nothing between the OS and the hardware to add functionality like snapshots. its not possible to have both. It really sounds like you want a Type-1 Hypervisor, but that would limit your hardware capabilities (only minimal games for instance).

Comment: It's mostly for a test system that I want to not have to reinstall the OS, run all the updates, etc. Maybe I'll get a couple of SSDs and use one of them as my base system and clone it over to the other one each time I want to start over fresh.
Thanks again for "sounding" this out with me. I'd be happy to mark your response as the answer so this Q can be closed.

Comment: cloning seems like the best bet for your situation if you don't want to run a hypervisor full time.

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution I've been looking for!! It is called Native Boot. Here are the details: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825691.aspx
I used a small partition on the drive to load Windows PE (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825045.aspx). The other bigger partition houses the VHDs.
Here is the awesome Scott Hanselman's take on it: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LessVirtualMoreMachineWindows7AndTheMagicOfBootToVHD.aspx
I used the Windows Sysinternals tool, Disk2VHD (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) to create a VHD from an existing Win10 install. So far everything works beautifully.

Comment: This would be a great answer if it was more the a bunch of links which, when I attempted to visit them, didn't even work

Comment: How're you snapshotting the VHDs?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek There are two ways, You can make copies of the full VHD, which is what I'm doing (yes, I realize this will be a space hog but space is not my concern for what I need this for). There is also the possibility of a "differencing VHD" which I haven't explored but might be useful so someone concerned about space.

Comment: @Kamal - I tried again, the links do not work, how about providing the critical information from them instead of asking me to do research.  I don't need the information myself, I don't have the problem describe, but knowing what is involved your answer seem incomplete.  *I personally know how to boot to a virtual machine.*  So my comments for you to clarify are for everyone else that doesn't.  You can read the help center on the reason why providing information from critical resource links is encourage, and answers which only link to that information, are often less helpful.

Comment: @Ramhound since you know how, maybe you can post your way of doing it and I'll mark that as the answer. The steps I followed from the links are extensive and I'd have to plagiarize the original so as not to leave out anything important since I can't be sure what parts can be left out and still have the thing work. Kinda weird that you cannot get the links to work. If you copied and pasted the URL in a browser, do they still not work?

Comment: @Kamal - I won't be doing that.  You should just improve this answer, so I can reverse my vote, **quoting source material and linking to the reference material isn't plagiarizing.**  I know exactly the reason the links don't work, the reason they don't work isn't important, and **has nothing to do with you improving this answer.**